# deixar invisível o <li> quando dentro não possui <ul>

Tags: jquery

Tenho um HTML que monta menu DROPDOWN.

Com JQUERY, estou tentando deixar invisível os itens que não possuem sublistas dentro.

Tentei utilizar o seguinte comando, mas não funcionou

`$('ul li :not(ul)').hide()`;

O código HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção 1</a>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="opcao_3.htm">Opção 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="opcao_4.htm">Opção 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção 5</a>
</li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção6</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="opcao_3.htm">Opção 7</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: o que eu fiz de errado pra ganhar um ponto negativo na pergunta?

Comment: Não seria melhor já gerar sem os ítens do que esconder depois?

Comment: Sim, seria, mas tenho que alterar umas estruturas no banco de dados, pois os menus são gerados automaticamente através de informações do mesmo. O Jquery seria uma solução paliativa.

Comment: Não saberia responder por quem negativou, mas você excluiu a pergunta anterior, que era praticamente igual e tinha uma resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que você comentou que a solução é paliativa, poderia esconder todos e mostrar os que interessam (método XGH):

```
$('body > ul > li').hide();
$('body > ul > li ul').parent().show();
```

Mas ainda acho que o ideal seria revisar a parte da geração dinâmica em vez disso.

### Exemplo:

```js
$('body > ul > li').hide();
$('body > ul > li ul').parent().show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="opcao_3.htm">Opção 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="opcao_4.htm">Opção 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção 5</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção6</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="opcao_3.htm">Opção 7</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Utilizei essa solução. Atendeu. Obrigado.

Comment: @Pedro se mudar de lugar o conjunto, lembre de trocar o `body` pelo elemento externo ( pode ser `div`, aí depende do seu código original)

Comment: já tinha retirado o body e colocado a ul#menu_superior no lugar... Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer assim: `$("body > ul > li:not(:has(ul))").hide();`

Ou assim:

```js
$('body>ul>li').filter(function(){
  return !$(this).find('ul').length;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção 1</a>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="opcao_3.htm">Opção 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="opcao_4.htm">Opção 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção 5</a>
</li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Opção6</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="opcao_3.htm">Opção 7</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Neste exemplo usei o `body`, terá de usar o parente direto ou dar uma class ao primeiro `ul` para evitar confusão com os `ul li` internos.